# SQL Group By with multiple columns - return all rows where the combination is greater than 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following data:

```
sequence    subSequence    Note
1           1              'A'
1           2              'B'
2           1              'C'
2           4              'D'
2           4              'E'
2           3              'F'
3           3              'G'
3           3              'H'
3           3              'I'
```

The following query returns rows where the combination of sequence and subSequence is greater than one.

```
SELECT sequence,subSequence,count(*) AS _rowCount
FROM [MyTable]
GROUP BY sequence,subSequence
HAVING count(*)>1
```

Result:

```
sequence subSequence _rowCount
2        4           2
3        3           3
```

I would like to return all rows where the combinations of sequence and subSequence are greater than one.

Result:

```
sequence subSequence Note
2        4           'D'
2        4           'E'
3        3           'G'
3        3           'H'
3        3           'I'
```

I've tried the following query but it's taking quite a while to execute and I'm not sure if it's correct. So I either need help optimizing it, or correcting it or any alternative queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM [MyTable]
WHERE sequence IN
        (SELECT sequence
        FROM [MyTable]
        GROUP BY sequence,subSequence
        HAVING count(*)>1)
    AND subSequence IN
        (SELECT subSequence
        FROM [MyTable]
        GROUP BY sequence,subSequence
        HAVING count(*)>1)
```

Comment: Added `sql-server`tag due to the non-standard `[..]` "quoting" style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY sequence, subSequence) AS rowCount
       FROM [MyTable]
     ) t
WHERE rowCount > 1;
```

Comment: Your query won't work because you're missing a comma: `t.*,` or `,COUNT(*)` will resolve.

Comment: I should add that this is generally the preferable way of getting such a result, in terms of performance.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT [MyTable].*, MySubQuery.rowCount
FROM [MyTable]
JOIN (
    SELECT sequence,subSequence,count(*) AS rowCount
    FROM [MyTable]
    GROUP BY sequence,subSequence
    HAVING count(*)>1
) As MySubQuery
ON MySubQuery.sequence = [MyTable].sequence
AND MySubQuery.subSequence= [MyTable].subSequence
```

Use a subquery and join it.

If this is still running slow I would recommend creating an index on `sequence,subSequence` like so:

```
 ALTER TABLE [MyTable]
 ADD INDEX idxSeqSubSeq (sequence,subSequence);
```

This will let the database engine take advantage of index to avoid looking at rows it doesn't need to consider.